# ADFS 2.0 signout redirect not functioning

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, authentication, adfs

In order to sign out of a web app using ADFS for authentication, using a URL that follows this form:

https://{DNS_name_of_RP_STS}/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0&wreply={post-sign-out_landing_URL}

works fine. The user is taken to an ADFS site page that notifies them that they've signed out. What isn't happening is redirecting back to the web app. I've spent a long time looking around online and I am pretty confused now as to if this is possible with the wreply parameter or not. There are a few spots on msdn and blogs where it is said to just work by supplying a wreply value, but it seems like most people are not having any luck with navigating back to the RP site.

Question: On signing out from ADFS, is it possible to automatically return to the RP app? Has anyone done this successfully? There's a "Sign in as different user" option that needs to end up with the user seeing the RP sign in page.

Thanks in advance to anyone who replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url cannot be just any url but rather the same exact url your application is registered in adfs for.

The redirect works and always worked for us.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thanks. Do you mean the Application URI specified in the Fed Utility wizard when configuring the application? So if I entered https://mysite.com/app there, the wreply parameter needs to be  https://mysite.com/app ?

Comment: @Wiktor - I'm using .NET 4.5 and ADFS v3.0. I can't get this to work.

Comment: @Wiktor - I'm using .NET 4.5 and ADFS v3.0. I can't get this to work. My ADFS RP identifier is https://yyy/SSO/Home/. My ADFS RP endpoint is https://yyy/SSO/. When I logout I see https://xxx/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0&wreply=https://yyy/SSO/Home/. Then https://yyy/SSO/?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0. But I stay on the ADFS logout page?

Comment: @nzpcmad: could you see how the logout page looks like? It is supposed to be a page with a list of iframes pointing to xx/yy?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0 to sign out consecutive apps and then a script should be at the end that redirects to wreply when a page fully loads. Is the last part just missing for some reason?

Comment: @Wiktor - Could you please ping me at my name A T g m a i l?

Comment: I experience the same issue as @nzpcmad describes. No matter what my Wreply value is, or whether this param is present, my sign out page does not disappear. I want the ADFS to auto redirect to my app on sign out. Could you share the solution? It seems that you found it, didn't you?

Comment: @Vladislav: adfs 2 or 3?

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla: adfs3. I have managed to find the solution. It was to register the Wreply url as a default endpoint at the ADFS. For details look here: https://www.sevecek.com/EnglishPages/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=93. Thanks!